Using Geometry Node Trim Curve Output For Spline-IK Rig
I want to use an output curve that had gone through Trim Curve in GeometryNodes for spline-IK rig. Is it possible to use the curve final result for the bone's spline-IK constraint?


No, this is not possible. With the Geometry Nodes modifier still on the object, the resulting curve is a procedural object. The Spline IK constraint will only take "real" curves into account.
And to even be able to select it in the constraint, first of all you would have to add the Geometry Nodes modifier to a curve object. If you use a mesh object like the default cube for example, you cannot choose it as Target for the constraint.
But, since the output is no "real" geometry, the curve which will be used for the constraint is the basic curve which you have in Edit Mode, without any modification by the GN nodetree.
In order to get "real" geometry, you would have to apply the Geometry Nodes modifier. However if you try to apply it in the Modifiers menu you will get an error message saying "Cannot apply constructive modifiers on curve. Convert curve to mesh in order to apply."
You can still directly apply it by using the shortcut Ctrl+A in the viewport and choosing Visual Geometry to Mesh. This will apply all modifiers which are on the object at once, but also convert it to a mesh. And then you can no longer use the (mesh) curve for the Spline IK constraint.
